# Passing parameters with Primefaces Mobile

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use JSF and PrimeFaces Mobile for my application.
I need that my user can choose between different files generated from a table in my db.
With PrimeFaces Mobile I have used so far p:dataList, but when I passing as a parameter the file selected by the user I have a problem:
when I call the method, always the last file load in the page is passed to the method.
I have to use something else?
How can I get to the parameter right?

Thanks in ADVANCE

MyCode:

```
  <p:dataList value="#{filesPersonaliBean.lfiles}" var="files" itemType="disc" >  
   <h:outputLink value="${filesPersonaliBean.prepareShareMobile(files)}" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{files.id} "/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{files.filename} " />

    </h:outputLink>
   </p:dataList>
```

Comment: Remove all-caps from your post and give it a title that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the mobile users guide:

"Wrap the content inside a column component in case you do a selection. This is a requirement in core UIData to process selection properly."